Cosmos emulator giving "No authority token provided" error when changing settings
I'm running the Azure Cosmos DB emulator locally, and all is working correctly with the database itself. However I'm trying to change the settings under Explorer -> Settings -> RU Threshold. When I click "Apply", the settings are not saved, but I get an error below:
Error occurred fetching keys for the account." No authority token provided
I have tried all the changes I can think of for this, including resetting the data and changing the port, and even reinstalling the emulator.
Is there a way to fix this error, so that I'm able to update the settings in Azure Cosmos DB Emulator?
Edit:
To clarify, I'm unable to edit any settings in the Azure Cosmos DB emulator, as I get this error every time.

update the emulator and check once

After my previous reinstall, I've checked and it's definitely on the latest version

check connection and reconnect once

This feature is only supported on Azure Portal. The RU threshold is for cost optimization and doesn't apply to the emulator, which is meant for dev/test.

fyi please don't make product commitments/promises here (I removed all of that). Aside from that, this really should have been a comment, along with close-voting the question, as it's a misunderstanding of a tool, not a programming question.

Thank you for the reply, I made a clarification in my question that all settings are broken with the same error message. So I think I still have the same issue with the error message. (It's also worth noting that the Cosmos UI specifically says "To prevent queries from using excessive RUs, Data Explorer has a 5,000 RU default limit. To modify or remove the limit, go to the Settings cog on the right and find "RU Threshold")
